# how to improve accuracy in google maps flutter app

Tags: flutter, maps

[current accuracy is too low](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWHrC.jpg)

i cant zoom much into maps what's the possible solution for it

Position _myPosition;
try {
Position newLocalData = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
_myPosition = newLocalData;
}catch(e) {
_myPosition = Position(
latitude: double.parse('0'),
longitude: double.parse('0'),
timestamp: DateTime.now(), accuracy: 1, altitude: 1, heading: 1, speed: 1, speedAccuracy: 1,
);
}
if(fromAddress) {
_position = _myPosition;
}else {
_pickPosition = _myPosition;
}
if (mapController != null) {
mapController.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(
CameraPosition(target: LatLng(_myPosition.latitude, _myPosition.longitude), zoom: 17),
));
}
// String _myPlaceMark;
String _getAddress = await getAddressFromGeocode(LatLng(_myPosition.latitude, _myPosition.longitude), context);
if(fromAddress) {
_address = placeMarkToAddress(_getAddress);
}
_loading = false;
notifyListeners();
}